# How to organize folders for Laravel on a conventional web host?

Tags: apache, url, laravel, hosting, directory

If I have the entire Laravel project inside `public_html`, I have to go to `http://domain.com/public` to access it, but if I put the contents of Laravel's `public` inside `public_html`, the rest of the files in Laravel would be looking for a folder called `public`, that is now called `public_html`.

Also, if I rename `public_html` to `public`, it won't work either.

I've tried changing `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public` to `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html'` on `/bootstrap/paths.php`

When I try to load `http:/domain.com` it says:

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/domain/bootstrap/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/domain/public_html:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 21
Warning: require(/home/domain/bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 21
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/domain/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 21
```

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public` to `'public' => __DIR__.'/../www'` on `/bootstrap/paths.php` doesn't work either

Comment: Can you create a symbolic link from public_html to public?

Comment: not really, i don't think i can access my web host using a shell

Comment: #1 on this page seems to be what you want: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Comment: i've tried renaming paths but i get the problem noted on EDIT 1. its like /public_html/index.php cant look above him

Comment: Did you check the folder permissions?

Comment: i contacted support, and they disabled open_basedir restriction, so not it works perfectly after changing the paths, thanks very much

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support disabled open_basedir restriction, so once again I changed the paths from public to public_html and it works now, no .htaccess magic needed either.